# Salesforce: Display reciprocal relationship on one related list

Tags: salesforce

I'm trying to create a custom object that shows relationships between Accounts. These are non-hierarchical, which is why I'm creating this separately from the Parent Account lookup.

So far, I created the object with a Master-Detail(Account) field and Lookup(Account) field. I'd like to show the reciprocal relationship in the related list on both Account records -- using only one related list!

I believe I need an apex trigger to create the reciprocal relationship data, but I'm just not sure how to do this. Any pointers? Or should I try a different solution altogether?

Thanks.

Comment: It will have to be 2 different rel. lists, with slightly diff. names (say "from" and "to"). I think it would help us if you could attach some drawing or maybe describe sample data set... Also - are you aware of the [Partner](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_partner.htm) object? And if you are - what made you think it's unsuitable? https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_erd_majors.htm

Comment: Am I incorrect in thinking the Partner object isn't really customizable? These Account relationships aren't traditional Partner Roles. In most cases, the relationship I'm talking about involves staff affiliated with both Accounts, or a loose Account-Account affiliation that might have start and end dates but certainly would need a description field.
I would like to create something similar to Relationships for Nonprofit Starter Pack [link](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003GLGPEA4), but involving Accounts rather than Contacts.

Comment: Yep, Partners are pretty much "from account X, to account Y, role" (and inserting it magically inserts a mirrored record with reversed role). No way to add more fields to it. Requirement to share staff across companies sounds like a job for AccountContactRole (again, not too customisable but should make you think about putting Contacts into the mix rather than making it acc. only link). I'll see if I can come up with something but this sounds like a job for proper consultant rather than asking random people on the net for advice ;)

Comment: Also - try cross-posting on salesforce.stackexchange.com or SF own communities. You have higher chance of meeting Administrators that faced something similar. It's not really a programming question - focus of StackOverflow.